# Time Helper Occur

Tags: cakephp

I just update my cakephp 1.3 to 2.1. And as I open my project this error occur.

Warning (2): call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'CakeTime' does not have a method 'relativeTime' [CORE\Cake\View\Helper\TimeHelper.php, line 120]

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the migration guide. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html

Use timeAgoInWords() instead because relativeTime() is deprecated and was just an alias for timeAgoInWords() and got removed.